# Mysql - How to display column from 2nd table based on values from 2 columns of 1st table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables,
measure:

```
id        currentgroup  nextgroup
1         1             2
2         2             5
3         3             24
4         99            NULL
```

description:

```
id       desc
1        First Level
2        Second Level
3        Third Level
4        Supervisor
5        Team Leader
.
.
99       CEO
```

and I would like to have this output

```
id       currentgroup   nextgroup
1        First Level    Second Level
2        Second Level   Team Leader
3        Third Level    DB department
4        CEO
```

These are the queries I tried. To display first two columns, this one is working:

```
SELECT id, description.desc
FROM measure 
INNER JOIN description ON measure.currentgroup=description.desc
WHERE measure.id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

**QUESTION: I'm unable to add the second column. I don't know how to define description.desc for the second column (nextgrouplevel). I added second join condition, but how to show this second column 'nextgroup'?**

```
SELECT id, description.desc
FROM measure 
INNER JOIN description ON measure.currentgroup=description.desc AND measure.nextgroup=description.desc
WHERE measure.id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join twice, once for each group. Since you have some measures without a next group, the second join should be a `left join`.

```
select 
    m.id,
    d1.desc current_group,
    d2.desc next_group
from 
    measure m
    inner join description d1 on d1.id = m.current_group
    left  join description d2 on d2.id = m.next_group
where m.id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, GMB, I tried it many times, but it didn't work for me. When I enter query: SELECT id, currentgroup, nextgroup FROM measure WHERE id=5; I get 9 rows with currentgroup and nextgroup with appropriate numbers. When I try to enter your select, I get 1800 rows, where first column is id with the same value of 5, in the second column there are just 2 strings, which are correctly transformed from numbers, but many times and in the third column nextgroup, there are all possible values (99) and also several times.